# How to use a common directory (Library) for many projects based on same framework?

Tags: php

I have started learning Zend Framework, Now I have created few almost 6 projects for practice, and in the library of each project i have copied the Zend Folder. Is there a way I can put this **Library** folder or **library/Zend** folder at a common place and include it through some other way, which can save my disk space.

Comment: So what is the problem? Create a folder, put all libraries in there and (optionally) add it to the include path via `set_include_path()`.

Comment: I'm not sure how much disk space you save by this, but I'm pretty sure it's not significant.

Comment: The main point for this is not to save space, but easier maintenance. Only need to update the library in one place.

Comment: In my opinion, if you have to make changes to library like zend, then it would be maybe better to have the lib in it's own project, because, who knows what will break in some other project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it anywhere and add it to the include path in php.ini,
or add it to the include path in you index.php at runtime, right before you start making calls to the bootstrap:

```
$path = 'path_to_zend';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

This way you do not have to rely on modifying php.ini, if you're deploying to a hosting that does not allow it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux, you can make use of soft-links.

For Windows, you can get by assigning a folder dedicated for third-party libraries and adding that directory in PHP's `include_path`. This is found in your `php.ini` file.

My style is having a `D:/PHP_Libraries` folder, put Zend Framework there, (and other libraries like Doctrine), and I have my `php.ini` like this:

```
include_path= ".;c:\php\includes;d:\PHP_Libraries"
```

You can do the same with Linux distros. It can be done on Macs, too.